# error: system/extras/perfprofd/Android.bp:77:1: "libperfprofd_record_proto" depends on undefined module "libquipper"

Tags: android, gnu-make, android-source

I am trying to *build* AOSP on `master` branch for *hikey960* board.
I followed below procedure to *build* AOSP.

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
$ repo sync -j24
```

After running below command I used to get terminal output(on `Android'O': 8.1.0` some include msg). But I didn't get in this case.

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
```

Please Note no terminal output after this command. Is this real issue?

```
$ lunch

You're building on Linux
Lunch menu... pick a combo:
 1. aosp_angler-userdebug
 .
 .
 36.hikey960-userdebug
 .
 .

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 36
```

Bellow is the few lines of  terminal output.

```
 PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=Q
 PLATFORM_VERSION=Q
 TARGET_PRODUCT=hikey960
 TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
 TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
 TARGET_ARCH=arm64
 /*Other ENV set*/

 $ make -j24
```

And below is the error

```
 [1/1] out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp      out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
 [58/59] glob prebuilts/ndk/cpufeatures.bp
 [82/82] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
 FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja 
 out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l      out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d      out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
 error: system/extras/perfprofd/Android.bp:77:1: "libperfprofd_record_proto" depends on undefined module "libquipper"
 ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
 11:21:46 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

As I am new to AOSP, I tried to find in most way, but still struggling to find solution, Expecting help here. Thank you in advance.

ref:  [Using Reference Boards](https://source.android.com/setup/build/devices)

Answer (score 0):

Did you establish the correct build environment ?

See  [Establishing a Build Environment](https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing)

Comment: Yes i've established correct build ENV.  On the same PC  I've tried with Android 8.1.0 and built images successfully. later before starting build for AOSP master branch, I've uninstalled JDK as per requirement given in website -`For the Java Development Kit (JDK), note the master branch of Android in AOSP comes with a prebuilt version of OpenJDK; so no additional installation is required.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build libquipper directly

```
. ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch hikey960-userdebug
cd external/perf_data_converter/src/quipper
mm
```

Comment: $cd external/perf_data_converter/src/quipper
`bash: cd: external/perf_data_converter/src/quipper: No such file or directory`
thank you for reply

Comment: Maybe something went wrong with the `repo init` then `repo sync` sequence.
According to [manifest on master](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/master/default.xml#281) you should have
  `<project path="external/perf_data_converter" name="platform/external/perf_data_converter" groups="pdk" />` which contains `external/perf_data_converter/src/quipper`
Check you have the right manifest and that `repo sync` succeed